# Filtered and copy to a new sheet (new sheet to be named as per filtered item)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master data which i need to separate into few sheets based on certain criteria and at the same time I would like the new sheet to be renamed to be the same as the criteria.

The VBA code is as below. Any idea that i can change the name "101 transport inc" to follow the name as per `Criteria1:=worksheets("CHK").Range("C5")`?

```
Sheets("RAW Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$U$2000").AutoFilter Field:=7, 
Criteria1:=Worksheets("CHK").Range("C5")
    Range("A7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "101 Transport Inc"
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Why not `.Name = Worksheets("CHK").Range("C5")` ? Is that an illegal worksheet name?

Answer (score 0):

.Name property of Worksheets allows you to change the name of a sheet. But, take care not to run this twice. Once the sheet is renamed, you will get a "Subscript Out of Range'" error if not handled properly.

```
Sheets("101 Transport Inc").Name = Worksheets("CHK").Range("C5")
```